# Why fatal exception?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

what's wrong with my code. I have no errors, but when I run the app and I press a button it shows me this. I think is possible because I didn't made a good sync with SQLite, probably that's the problem. What should I do to reduce the errors ? My app just go "force quit" after I press a button, I'm a begginer with android studio, I hardly know to use all the tools, and maybe that is the main problem here.

```
        E/SQLiteLog: (1) near ",": syntax error
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.password, PID: 5700
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
            at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
            at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
         Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ",": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE users (userid TEXT PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT,
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
            at com.example.password.UsersDBHelper.onCreate(UserDBHelper.kt:15)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:294)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:194)
            at com.example.password.UsersDBHelper.readAllUsers(UserDBHelper.kt:90)
            at com.example.password.MainActivity.showAllUsers(MainActivity.kt:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
            at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:60255', transport: 'socket'

My codes :

activity_main

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context="com.example.password.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/android_password_generator"
        android:textSize="20sp"

        android:padding="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_userid"
            android:hint="@string/website"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="Website"
            android:inputType="text" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_name"
            android:hint="@string/password"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints="Password for website"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_add_user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="addUser"
            android:text="@string/add"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_delete_user"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="deleteUser"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_show_all"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="showAllUsers"
            android:text="@string/show_all"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            tools:ignore="OnClick" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_entries"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

UserModel

    package com.example.password

class UserModel(val userid: String, val name: String)

DBContract:

    package com.example.password

import android.provider.BaseColumns

object DBContract {

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    class UserEntry : BaseColumns {
        companion object {
            var TABLE_NAME = "users"
            var COLUMN_USER_ID = "userid"
            var COLUMN_NAME = "name"

        }
    }
}

UserDBHelper 

    package com.example.password

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import java.util.*

class UsersDBHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES)
        onCreate(db)
    }

    override fun onDowngrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion)
    }

    @Throws(SQLiteConstraintException::class)
    fun insertUser(user: UserModel): Boolean {
        // Gets the data repository in write mode
        val db = writableDatabase

        // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_USER_ID, user.userid)
        values.put(DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_NAME, user.name)


        // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
        db.insert(DBContract.UserEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values)

        return true
    }

    @Throws(SQLiteConstraintException::class)
    fun deleteUser(userid: String): Boolean {
        // Gets the data repository in write mode
        val db = writableDatabase
        // Define 'where' part of query.
        val selection = DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_USER_ID + " LIKE ?"
        // Specify arguments in placeholder order.
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(userid)
        // Issue SQL statement.
        db.delete(DBContract.UserEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs)

        return true
    }

    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    fun readUser(userid: String): ArrayList<UserModel> {
        val users = ArrayList<UserModel>()
        val db = writableDatabase
        val cursor: Cursor?
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DBContract.UserEntry.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_USER_ID + "='" + userid + "'", null)
        } catch (e: SQLiteException) {
            // if table not yet present, create it
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES)
            return ArrayList()
        }

        var name: String

        if (cursor!!.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
                name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_NAME))


                users.add(UserModel(userid, name))
                cursor.moveToNext()
            }
        }
        return users
    }

    @SuppressLint("Recycle")
    fun readAllUsers(): ArrayList<UserModel> {
        val users = ArrayList<UserModel>()
        val db = writableDatabase
        val cursor: Cursor?
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DBContract.UserEntry.TABLE_NAME, null)
        } catch (e: SQLiteException) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES)
            return ArrayList()
        }

        var userid: String
        var name: String

        if (cursor!!.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast) {
                userid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_USER_ID))
                name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_NAME))


                users.add(UserModel(userid, name))
                cursor.moveToNext()
            }
        }
        return users
    }

    companion object {
        // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
        var DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        var DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db"

        private val SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + DBContract.UserEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_USER_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," +
                    DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"

        private val SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBContract.UserEntry.TABLE_NAME
    }

}


MainActivity 

    package com.example.password


import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var usersDBHelper : UsersDBHelper

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        usersDBHelper = UsersDBHelper(this)
    }



    fun addUser(view: View) {
        val userid = this.edittext_userid.text.toString()
        val name = this.edittext_name.text.toString()

        val result = usersDBHelper.insertUser(UserModel(userid = userid,name = name))
        //clear all edittext s

        this.edittext_name.setText("")
        this.edittext_userid.setText("")
        this.textview_result.text = "Added user : $result"
        this.ll_entries.removeAllViews()
    }

    fun deleteUser(view: View) {
        val userid = this.edittext_userid.text.toString()
        val result = usersDBHelper.deleteUser(userid)
        this.textview_result.text = "Deleted user : $result"
        this.ll_entries.removeAllViews()
    }

    fun showAllUsers(view: View) { val users = usersDBHelper.readAllUsers()
        this.ll_entries.removeAllViews()
        users.forEach {
            val tvuser = TextView(this)
            tvuser.textSize = 30F
            tvuser.text = it.name + " - "
            this.ll_entries.addView(tvuser)
        }
        this.textview_result.text = "Fetched " + users.size + " users"}
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error... please show the code thats being run

Comment: All the code is in the question

Comment: you should probably check your SQL syntax in your android code, there is a typo mistake there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your create table statement is wrong. You close the statement with ',' instead of ')'. Also all of SQL statements need to be closed with a semicolon ';'.

Try insetad of:

```
private val SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DBContract.UserEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_USER_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," +
                DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
```

use this:

```
private val SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
        "CREATE TABLE " + DBContract.UserEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_USER_ID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY," +
                DBContract.UserEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT);"
```

This should fix your initial error.
You can read more about SQL statements and their Syntax here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp